# How can I make this custom wordpress ordered list split into a second column after the fifth list item is generated?

Tags: wordpress, loops, multiple-columns

I made this function to print an ordered list of posts with the category principle (9 in total). That part works fine. What I'm struggling with is getting it to split into two columns after the 5th list item is generated.

```
    <ol class="rounded-list" data-columns="2">
                    <?php
                    query_posts('cat=principle$posts_per_page=-1');
                        if (have_posts()) :
                            while (have_posts()) :
                                the_post(); ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title();?></a>
                                    </li>
                            <?php endwhile;
                        endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?>
                </ol>
```

Comment: I see a quick solution to add .rounded-list { -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; }

Comment: Hi yuyokk, 

Thanks for that. I tried that earlier and it didn't work because I added the column count to my .rounded-list a{} rather than its own style. I feel so derpy now for not realizing that.